# Eclipse: vertical ruler listener never called

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to implement a vertical ruler listener in eclipse. I implemented the `IPartListener2` interface, and when a java editor is opened I register the listener. The problem is that the listener never gets called when the vertical ruler is clicked. If I call the CompositeRuler.fireAnnotationSelected(), the listener is called as expected.

I think this might be a bug but I want to be sure before filling a bug in bugzilla. Can someone point what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the IPartListener2 class:

```java
public class EditorListener implements IPartListener2 {

    @Override
    public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
        IWorkbenchPart part = partRef.getPart(true);
        if (part != null && part instanceof IEditorPart)
            configureJavaEditor((IEditorPart) part);
    }

    // other IPartListener2 methods...

    private void configureJavaEditor(IEditorPart editorPart) {
        Object obj = ((JavaEditor) editorPart).getAdapter(IVerticalRulerInfo.class);
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof IVerticalRulerInfoExtension) {
            ((IVerticalRulerInfoExtension) obj).addVerticalRulerListener(new VerticalRulerListener());
            if (obj instanceof CompositeRuler) 
                ((CompositeRuler) obj).fireAnnotationSelected(null); // -> listener called
        }
    }
}
```

The vertical ruler listener just prints the method that is being called.

At first I thought this could be happening because I used the JavaEditor to get to the vertical ruler (JavaEditor access is discouraged), so I changed from JavaEditor to AbstractDecoratedTextEditor, that is the next class in the editors class hierarchy, but the problem was still the same. I'm out of ideas. Any hints on what's wrong?

Comment: I solved the problem implementing the `MouseListener` interface directly, using the `IVerticalRulerInfo.toDocumentLineNumber()` to translate from y-coordinate to line number when a `MouseEvent` arrives, but I still want to know why the `VerticalRulerListener` didn't work...

Comment: but i guess it's allready your post: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/870740/

Comment: I tried it, the vertical ruler listener doesn't do anything besides the constructor